# Export a Google Fusion table/view with a few Filter Options visible

Tags: google-fusion-tables

How can I export a Google Fusion Table/view with some of the possible filter options present in the view .

I don't want that my users need to select  the filters category every time.
It would be nice if I can lock them in place.
In the given screenshot Region and Population are visible and ready to use.
When I  publish it or give my users a link, I want it to open so that they see the same. The users click on a link and have te same view as in the screenshot.

I didn't find any useful info [here](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2562121?hl=en).

[image: I would like to publish it like this]

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

If you send users the URL shown when you are viewing the map tab, they will see it exactly as you left it.

Note there is currently an intermittent problem with Fusion Tables such that filter selections and map locations are not properly saved. That will be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of this, this explains a lot that some users didn't understand my problem.